# multiple if stamens inside for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.reviews.length; i++){
    if(data.reviews[i].rating.overall > 80){
      console.log(i);
      if(i > 1){
        console.log('more than 80 and more than 1');
      }
      else{
        console.log('more than 80 and only 1');
      }

    }
}
```

and a reviews array as follow:

```
"reviews":[
{
"rating":{"overall": 91}
},
{
"rating":{"overall": 77}
},
{
"rating":{"overall": 94}
},
{
"rating":{"overall": 74}
}
],
```

I have some conditions that I need to meet to append some HTML:

1) if the reviews overall is more than 80 and there is more than one reviews (append slide show)

2) if the reviews overall is more than 80 and there is only one review (append plain text, jus tone review without slideshow)

Based on the reviews data provided I should get `console.log('more than 80 and more than 1');` printed only twice instead in my console I get:

```
more than 80 and only 1  
more than 80 and only 1  
more than 80 and more than 1
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clearer what exactly you are asking?

Comment: What I am getting in the console is not what I think the script should print

Comment: Remember array indexes are **0 based**. Also, what the console is printing is exactly what you've described it should.

Comment: Your code makes very little sense. Why do you care if a high rating occurs in the first two indices of `data.reviews`? You need to clarify what you are trying to do with words.

Comment: All I need is "if there is more than one review with a score of 80 than append a p tag only with the review in it, if more than  one review with the score of 80 append a slideshow"

Comment: I suspect some code is missing. If I set a var called data as an object containing the reviews snippet and then run the for loop, I get a different output: 0\\
more than 80 and only 1\\
2\\
more than 80 and more than 1\\

Comment: The data is coming from an ajax call

Comment: Your code running in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/xtxRGTTRbnS3PlolKy3l?p=preview) does not give the console output you said, it gets the expected output.

Comment: My code is wrong because it's printing both condition at the same time. I need either one or the other

Comment: In your comment above, you wrote: *"if there is more than one review with a score of 80..., if more than one review with the score of 80..."* So you want two different things to be done if there is more than one?

Comment: ...in any case, it seems like you want to perhaps discover how many reviews have greater than 80. If so, use `.filter()` on the array to filter it down to the subset that you want, and then perform operations based on how many were discovered. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sjf4cp0h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, then you simply need to change the inner `if` statement to check how many reviews there are - not the counter for iterating them...

```js
var data = {
    "reviews": [
        {
            "rating":{"overall": 91}
        },
        {
            "rating":{"overall": 77}
        },
        {
            "rating":{"overall": 94}
        },
        {
            "rating":{"overall": 74}
        }
    ]
};

for (var i = 0, l = data.reviews.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (data.reviews[i].rating.overall > 80) {
        if (l > 1) {  // check the overall count, instead of the current index
            document.write('more than 80 and more than 1<br />');
        }
        else {
            document.write('more than 80 and only 1<br />');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this~

```
      var count = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < data.reviews.length; i++){
        if(data.reviews[i].rating.overall > 80){
          count++;
          }
      }
      if(count > 1){
            console.log('more than 80 and more than 1');
          }
          else{
            console.log('more than 80 and only 1');
          }
            //current.find(".reviews-wrapper ul").append("<li data-orbit-slide='headline-" + [i] + "'>" + data.reviews[i].notes + "<p class='bold'>" + data.reviews[i].user.nickname + ", " + data.reviews[i].groupInformation.groupTypeCode + ", " + data.reviews[i].groupInformation.age + "</p></li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to count rating over 80 ?

```
var count = 0

for(var i = 0; i < data.reviews.length; i++){
    var rating = data.reviews[i].rating.overall;

    switch (rating) {
        case (rating > 80):
              count++;
            break;
    }
}

if ( count > 1 ) {
    console.log('more than 80 and more than 1');
} else {
    console.log('more than 80 and only 1');
}
```

With switch/case if you wanted to go further you could append the html you want with each bracket

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue you are having with the code you provided is that it does not match up to your question.
You are asking for three cases:

- If there is more than one review and the overall is above 80
- If there is only one review and the overall is above 80
- Anything else (effectively anything less than 80 overall)

However, you are using 'i' your iterator to answer the question of 'Is there more than one review', when in this context it answers the question 'Is the current iteration the third or later iteration of this loop over the reviews' (Due to the zero index of arrays, 'i>1' will be true on the third iteration).

It is unclear from your question whether you only want to count reviews over 80 towards your total or just the total number of reviews, so I'll give you a couple loop options:

```
var sizeString=''
if(data.reviews.length > 1) {
   sizeString=' and more than 1';
}
for(var i = 0; i< data.reviews.length; i++) {
  if(data.reviews[i].rating.overall > 80){
    console.log('more than 80'+sizeString);
  }
}
```

Or, if only counting when there's more than 1 over-80 review:

```
var sizeString=''
var numOver80=0;
for(var i = 0; i< data.reviews.length; i++) {
  // This will simply find out if there are at least two over 80 ratings
  if(data.reviews[i].rating.overall > 80){
    numOver80++;
    if(numOver80 > 1){
      sizeString=' and more than 1';
      break; // Unless you want to get the actual total
    }
  }
}
for(var i = 0; i< data.reviews.length; i++) {
  if(data.reviews[i].rating.overall > 80) {
    console.log('more than 80'+sizeString);
  }
}
```

Hopefully these get you pointed in the right direction.